# how to use "koa-favicon", getting "Not Found"

Tags: node.js, koa

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const favicon = require('koa-favicon');
app.use(favicon());
app.listen(3008);
```

"favicon.ico" exist in root directory (__dirname). In Chrome I opening http://localhost:3008/ and see "network/favicon.ico" query with status 404:

Request URL: http://localhost:3008/favicon.ico
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
[enter image description here][2]
Why ? favicon.ico exist there

Comment: I have a similar problem with `koa-sendfile` (Windows). It seems that `"C:\A1\B2\C3"` is treated as `".\A1\B2\C3"`, so the file is not found (you can check it by adding an error handler at the beginning of the middleware chain). A workaround is to use a relative path instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify path to icon.

```
const path = require('path');

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico')));
```

Check this [code](https://github.com/koajs/favicon/blob/c97b52ff4d3e8ae9d111005b544b9e63445c1602/index.js#L20-L26). Middleware returns pass through function if you haven't specified icon path.

> ```
> module.exports = function (path, options){
>   if (!path) {
>     return (ctx, next) => {
>       if ('/favicon.ico' != ctx.path) {
>         return next();
>       }
>     };
>   } ...
> ```

Comment: app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico')));
the same result...Request URL: http://localhost:3008/favicon.ico Request Method: GET Status Code: 404 Not Found

Comment: but path.join(__dirname, 'favicon.ico') exist

Comment: @Алекс Make sure you have restarted the server and cleaned up browser cache just in case. If it doesn't  help you could set a breakpoint inside middleware function to check if it actually running and why it is not working as expected.

Comment: After load in chrome browser http://localhost:xxxx/, then "network/favicon.ico" auto-query to root directory г localhost:xxxx/favicon.ico. This file .ico exist there. What can I do in order to server give this existing "favicon.ico" instead of error "Not Found" ?

Comment: @Алекс It doesn't "query to root directory". It sends request to you server. This request will be processed by the middleware which reads icon file you have specified from anywhere in the file system. There are like 50 lines of code. Just drop debugger statement inside the function and launch your app in debug mode.

Comment: @Алекс Short article describing how to debug node app https://blog.risingstack.com/how-to-debug-nodej-js-with-the-best-tools-available/